# What is the difference between CMP and SCEP protocol?

Tags: certificates, protocols, scep, cmp

1. What is the difference between **CMP** and **SCEP** protocol?
2. Which one is better?

Comment: CMP stands for Certificate Management Protocol

Answer (score 5):

[CMP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4210) is a generic protocol which aims at covering most (if not all) network exchanges involving a Certificate Authority; e.g. it includes messages for a CA who wants to announce that it has a new key pair. The protocol is rather complex, and has been around for quite some time (first published [version](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2510) is from 1999).

[SCEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Certificate_Enrollment_Protocol) is a specialized protocol which has a smaller scope; it concentrates on *enrollment* and *CRL obtention*, and is definitely client/server (all messages are requests sent to the CA, and responses from the CA, while CMP allows for CA-driven exchanges). SCEP is not a formal standard; it is not even a RFC but still a [draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nourse-scep-23) which is 1. expired, and 2. destined to become an "historic" RFC. SCEP, though, is a big *de facto* "standard" by being what Cisco hardware tends to do.

The second paragraph of the latest SCEP draft says it all, so let me quote it *in extenso*:

> This specification defines a protocol, Simple Certificate Enrollment
> Protocol (SCEP), for certificate management and certificate and CRL
> queries in a closed environment.  While widely deployed, this
> protocol omits some certificate management features, e.g. in-band
> certificate revocation transactions, which can significantly enhance
> the security achieved in a PKI.  The IETF protocol suite currently
> includes two certificate management protocols with more comprehensive
> functionality: Certificate Management Protocol (CMP) [RFC4210] and
> Certificate Management over CMS (CMC) [RFC5272].  Environments that
> do not require interoperability with SCEP implementations SHOULD use
> the above-mentioned, PKIX-standard certificate management protocols.
> In light of the functionality gap between this specification and the
> two IETF standards track protocols, this specification is being
> published as Historic.  Even when interoperability with the installed
> base of SCEP implementations is needed, implementers are encouraged
> to support one of these comprehensive standards track certificate
> management protocols in addition to the protocol defined in this
> specification.  This implementation strategy balances near-term
> requirements for interoperability with longer term security goals.

So there you have it: you are encouraged to support and use CMP, and you should envision SCEP mostly for compatibility with legacy deployments, and even then you know that SCEP won't do everything that can be done with CMP.

Answer (score 0):

Since that question, SCEP is now fully standardized as RFC 8894 (after a measly 20 years) and is still one of the most widely used enrollment protocols. It can now handle ECC key enrollment, which was unhandled initially.

The ACME protocol was created (for LetsEncrypt) and is especially good at enrolling web servers.

Most usages are covered by those two, for most complex usages there is CMP, CMC and EST with less support from the industry. EST being mostly a subset of the insanely complex CMC with elements of CMP. Cisco is now pulling EST with all its weight, and is likely the one among those three.

Note that many use cases of the protocols are not actually used because handled in other ways. CRL distribution and CA rollover are typically handled in other ways for example (and CRL shouldn't really be used but possibly for an OCSP responder).